# Xcode to fetch contact email address from addressbook

Tags: iphone, addressbook

How can I fetch email address of a contact in iPhone address book?
I have an app in which I want to import any contact from address book with all his information like name,number,email.
Name,number is working fine I want to fetch address too.
Please help with the code function.

Answer (score 5):

You should add frame work `AddressBook.framework` and add `#import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>` in .m file.

To  fetch contact email address from address book::

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
NSMutableArray *allEmails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:CFArrayGetCount(people)];
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++) {
    ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
    ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(emails); j++) {
        NSString* email = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, j);
        [allEmails addObject:email];
        [email release];
    }
    CFRelease(emails);
}
NSLog(@"All Mails:%@",allEmails);
CFRelease(addressBook);
CFRelease(people);
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Edit::

You should use delegate `- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person` method. When you select any person in contact list this method will call. Try this one...

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{

ABMultiValueRef  emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
NSString *emailId = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 0);//0 for "Home Email" and 1 for "Work Email".
NSLog(@"Email:: %@",emailId);

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i want to fetch email of a particular selected contact

Comment: This code is fetching all email addresses of all contacts in addressbook but i want to fetch just email address of one selected contact at a time.Please help.Thanks

Comment: THanks alot for reply.It helped me in showing result in output but not showing in simulator :(